# jqSuite PHP date picker dialog format not working

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid, datepicker, jqgrid-php

I have jqSuite up and running, everything works great, except when I'm trying to edit a date.  The date source format is `YYYY-mm-dd (MySQL)`, and when displaying, I use the following, which works perfectly for displaying.

```
"formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d","newformat"=>"m/d/Y")
```

However when I pop up an edit dialog, the datepicker opens as `dd/mm/yy (javascript)` is in the wrong format, despite initializing the datepicker with the correct format.

```
$datepicker = <<<DATEPICK
function(el){
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy'});
    },200);
}
DATEPICK;

...

"editoptions"=>array("dataInit"=>"js:".$datepicker)
```

Everything except for the format of the datepicker when editing works as intended.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: check jquery lib, and see what format it has for date picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your `datepicker()` for each input on document load..

Use a `class` as a hook on your input:

```
<input class="my-datepicker">
```

Then call `datepicker` on elements with that class with your default configuration:

```
$('.my-datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'm/d/Y'
});
```

When you need a different configuration, use/assign a different class name.

You can also use [`setDefaults`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.setDefaults) (probably what you're looking for):

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'm/d/Y'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Does adding this code work?

```
$grid->setUserDate("m/d/Y");
$grid->datearray = array("BirthDate");
```

Where "BirthDate" is the name of your date column.  You might also want to try one of the following lines:

```
$grid->setUserTime("m/d/Y");
$grid->setDatepicker("BirthDate");
```

For more information see [this page in the docs](http://www.trirand.net/documentation/php/_2v212r62k.htm) and [this example from the demo page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/editing_data/datepicker_editdialog/default.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the / for a - just to see if that works. At least you know if it's the / or something else causing the problem.